# Show negative part of y-axis for bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have managed to plot a bar chart of mean values of each year's distributions with the 95% CI standard error bar as below.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8JXQ.jpg)
However, I want to display the negative part of y-axis as well for rectangle selector use later, which looks something like this.
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut5OX.jpg)

Here is the code that I used to create the bar plot:

```
%matplotlib qt
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                    np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                    np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                    np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

mean = []
ci95 = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    globals()['avg%s' % (i+92)] = np.mean(df.iloc[i])
    globals()['semci%s' % (i+92)] = np.std(df.iloc[i])*1.96/math.sqrt(len(df.iloc[i]))
    mean.append(globals()['avg%s' % (i+92)])
    ci95.append(globals()['semci%s' % (i+92)])

year = np.array(['1992','1993','1994','1995'])
x_pos = np.arange(len(year))

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    global x1, x2, y1, y2
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    probs = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        globals()['btw%s' % (i+92)] = 0 #create variables to count no. of values in the range
        for j in range(len(df.iloc[i])): #for loop through all values of each year's distribution
            if (df.iloc[i,j] > y1) & (df.iloc[i,j] < y2):#check if a value falls in a given range 
                globals()['btw%s' % (i+92)] += 1 #add 1 to the variables created every time a satisfying value detected
        #compute probability that a distribution's value falls in a given range
        #by dividing no. of values in range by sample size of the distribution
        globals()['probs%s' % (i+92)] = globals()['btw%s' % (i+92)]/len(df.iloc[i])
        probs.append(globals()['probs%s' % (i+92)])
        
    my_cm = plt.get_cmap("Greens")
    ax.bar(x_pos, mean, yerr=ci95, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black', capsize=10, color = my_cm(np.array(probs)))
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
    ax.set_xticklabels(year)
    ax.set_title('Assignment 3')
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)

def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x_pos, mean, yerr=ci95, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black', capsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(year)
ax.set_title('Assignment 3')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)


plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) to set the limits of the y-axis.
For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ylim(bottom=-30000)
```

**EDIT:** I confirm that setting the y limit to -30000 allows to visualize the negative part of the y-axis.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,20))
ax.bar(x_pos, mean, yerr=ci95, align='center', alpha=0.5,     ecolor='black', capsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)

ax.set_xticklabels(year)
ax.set_title('Assignment 3')
ax.set_ylim(bottom=-30000)
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
```

In addition, if you are unsatisfied with the aspect ratio, you can control the figure size directly in `subplots`. For instance, setting `figsize` to (5,20) returns the following figure: [image]

Comment: I tried ylim with top value of 6000 as well but the bar lengths are unnecessarily bigger, so I think the plot should be scaled smaller to include all the bars and negative part of y-axis as well

Comment: If you are using matplotlib's `bar` function, you can control the height and the width of the bars: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Comment: Please provide us with a MRE so that we can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited my reply to address how to control the figure size.